# Is there any settings in MongoDb Compass to Convert BinData(3, 'ZF+oPxdXYkWz/CyWP2avpg==') in to UUID

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I want to convert the BinData(3, 'ZF+oPxdXYkWz/CyWP2avpg==') in UUID format without modifying (or) changing the original data type of the fields.So is there any settings available in MongoDb Compass to convert this.

I have tried so many things but i couldn't find

Comment: AFAIK, compass doesn't have a built-in setting to convert BinData directly to UUID format

Answer (score 1):

The problem with legacy UUIDs (binary subtype 3) is that the byte order was not clearly defined in the BSON specification.  This left the drivers free to use their internal byte ordering when converting the UUID to BSON for storage.

The binary data represented by that base64 string is

> 645fa83f17576245b3fc2c963f66afa6

If that data was stored by the python, java, or c# driver the UUID could be one of:

- 645fa83f-1757-6245-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
- 3fa85f64-5717-4561-b3fc-2c963f66afa6
- 45625717-3fa8-5f64-b3fc-2c963f66afa6

Other drivers could have used different byte ordering.

There is no single algorithm to convert from that binary data back to the original UUID without having additional information, so there can be no generic function to perform that conversion.

The usual way to deal with that is to use the new UUID format (binary subtype 4) which requires byte ordering to comply with RFC-4122